# Is there a use case for `newtype T = MkT (T -> T)`?

Tags: haskell

The paper ["System F with Type Equality Coercions"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ext-f/) by Sulzmann, Chakravarty, and Peyton Jones illustrates the translation of Haskell's `newtype` into System FC with the following example:

```
newtype T = MkT (T -> T)
```

As I understand it, barring `unsafePerformIO`, the only possible values of this type are `MkT id` and `MkT undefined` because of parametricity. I'm curious if there are some actual uses for this (or a similar) definition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Parametricity is about the values of types with **variables**.  `T` has no variables, so parametricity does not apply.  Infact, T has many inhabitants

```
ap :: T -> T -> T
ap (MkT f) t = f t

idT :: T
idT = MkT id

constT :: T
constT = MkT $ \t -> MkT $ \_ -> t

axiom_sT :: T
axiom_sT = MkT $ \f -> MkT $ \g -> MkT $ \a -> (g `ap` a) `ap` (f `ap` a)
```

The type `T` is an implementation of the [Untyped Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), a universal formal system equivalent in power to a Turing machine.  The three functions above (plus `ap`) form the SKI calculus, an equivalent formal system.

It is possible to encode any Haskell datatype into `T`.  Consider the type for natural numbers

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

we can encode `Nat` into `T`

```
church :: Nat -> T
church Zero     = MkT $ \f -> MkT $ \x -> x
church (Succ n) = MkT $ \f -> MkT $ \x -> f `ap` (church n)
```

now, you are partially correct though.  There is no way in Haskell to write the inverse function of this (so far as I know).  Which is really a shame.  Although you can write a sort of psuedo inverse with the type `T -> IO Nat`.  Also, my understanding is the GHCs optimizer can die on recursive `newtypes` (someone please correct me if I am wrong about this, because I would like to go back to using them).

Instead, the type

```
data T = MkT (T -> T) | Failed String
```

with

```
ap (MkT f)    a = f a
ap (Failed s) _ = Failed s
```

which is the lambda calculus with exceptions, can be used in a fully invertable way.

In conclusion, in one sense `T` is not a useful type at all, but in another sense it is **the most useful type of all**.

Comment: Unfortunately you're not wrong -- at least, GHC 7.6's inliner can panic on some expressions involving types with negative recursion (this can happen with `data` as well as `newtype`). Positive recursion -- i.e. on the right side of `->` -- should be fine, though.